# Organizing an Angular app into multiple sections

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to break my Angular app out into the following sections and have a few questions:

```
auth
    login (only public the page in entire system, when user logs in they get directed to admin-portal or user-portal based on certain variables)

admin-portal
    layout (layout for admin portal) -component
    dashboard (dashboard for admin portal) -component
    users (user management for admin portal) -component

user-portal
    layout (layout for user portal) -component
    dashboard (dashboard for user portal) -component
    projects (project management for user portal) -component
```

1. Should I make each one of these sections its own module with its own
   routes?
2. Is it possible to have duplicate component names for example
   dashboard.component in each module?
3. In the routes my plan is to make admin-portal and user-portal parent routes with their own AuthGuards on them and then all of the child routes within them.

Comment: Addressing `2`, while it may be possible to do this if you make sure they have different `selectors` or exist in completely different scopes, I think it is better design to give them different names, such as `admin-dashboard`, and `user-dashboard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is common to break an Angular application into multiple sections (or features) and to build a "feature module" for each feature.

As suggested in the comments ... it is a much better design to give your components unique names. It will be much less confusing when reading the code.

Yes, you can build guards on your routes and define child routes.